# Django REST framework API: PrimaryKeyRelatedField

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am fairly new to Django Rest Framework API.

My question is that can I declare a PrimaryKeyRelatedField in serializers.Serializer subclass? Or it has to be in serializers.ModelSerializer subclass?

For example, I used to have serializer as following:

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=False)
    ## and more general fields
    class Meta:
        model = Example
```

which works fine.

Then I changed it to:

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=False)
    ## and more general fields
```

where I got a error:

```
AttributeError: 'SerializerOptions' object has no attribute 'model'
```

What I am sure is that this error is caused by 'author' field (error will be gone if you comment it out)

So does this indicate that I cannot use foreign key type field in general Serializer?

By the way, if you are curious why I change my serializer from ModelSerializer to Serializer is because that I want to include some additional fields (which doesn't exist in any models) in order to create an new Example instance. By default .restore_object() method simple call Example(**attrs) to create new instance, which will causes a field error.

Answer (score 0):

You need a model, because you want to serialize a db relationship.

[Here is the doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#serializer-relations)